# Why isn't the GPO showing up in gpresult?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have a GPO made for a specific OU that I have a test device in. Other test GPOs work fine and show up on the device in gpresult. The GPO I'm having issues with is set to run a PowerShell script on login. It does not appear under applied or denied in the gpresult. Only info I've found even remotely related was about needing authenticated users read delegation but I already have that set up.

The GPO just has this under PowerShell script logon:

```
\\MyDomain\netlogon\log_user_and_computer_nochecking.ps1
```

The script itself:

```
$username = whoami.exe
$computername = Get-ComputerInfo | Select-Object CsDNSHostName -ExpandProperty CsDNSHostName
$usercomp = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        UserName     = $username
        ComputerName = $computername
    }
)
#$usercomp | Export-Csv -Path "C:\util\temp\anyconnect_users.csv" -Append
$usercomp | Export-Csv -Path "\\MyDomain\group\CDS\DomainWide\Common\logs\anyconnect_users.csv" -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a gpo made for a specific ou that I have a test **device** in

&

> the gpo just has this under powershell script logon:

Those two line does not fit. A computer OU and a user action. You can't apply user settings GPO when the GPO is linked to a computer account, and the inverse too.

Please link the GPO the the user OU and make a WMI filter to target the remote computer in worst case.

A WMI filter like that;

SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE Name LIKE 'COMPUTERNAME'

Else you need to enable Loopback processing.

Comment: The GPO affects an action on User Login on said device. It's targeting all users who log on to a device in that ou. How is that not allowed by GPO? I am trying to get a report generated from certain devices when a user logs in effectively to tell me which user has which device in this ou.

Comment: @Fox Script configured under Computer policy run at the computer startup, as it's a computer policy. If you need to target a specific computer for all users, it must be a user gpo restricted to that computer. By logic a user GPO would need to be created and linked to an user OU, if you link a user gpo to a computer OU, you need loopback processing. "... In some cases, users may need policy applied to them based on the location of the computer object alone. You can use the Group Policy loopback feature to apply Group Policy Objects (GPOs) that depend only on which computer the user signs in to"

Comment: @Fox For more information; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/loopback-processing-of-group-policy  or if you dont want to setup that you can use the WMI tip  I shared too.

Comment: I appreciate the information